# Creating flat object form nested json with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know that Jackson allows to create flat json using `@JsonUnwrapped` so that object of a class like

```
public class Person {
    public int age;
    @JsonUnwrapped public Name name;

    public class Name {
        public String first, last;
    }
}
```

would be serialized into

```
{"age" : 99, "first" : "Name", "last" : "Surname"}
```

however, I can't find a way to do the opposite - have a class like

```
public class Person {
    public int age;
    public String firstName, lastName;
}
```

and have its object serialized into and deserialized from

```
{"age" : 99, "name" : {"first" : "Name", "last" : "Surname"}}
```

Is this possible using Jackson 1.9?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The whole _wrapped_ concept would make much more sense with an encapsulating class/object such as `Name`.

Comment: yup, I think you're going to need a Name object to hold the first and last

Comment: That's disappointing, thank you anyways... Something like `@JsonProperty("name.first") public String firstName;` would be great...

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon this rather old question as I was looking for the same. I ended up doing this:

```
public class Person {
  public int age;

  @JsonIgnore
  public String firstName, lastName;

  protected void setName(PersonName name) {
    firstName = name.first;
    lastName = name.last;
  }

  protected PersonName getName() {
    return new PersonName(firstName, lastName);
  }

  protected static class PersonName {
    private final String first, last;

    @JsonCreator
    public PersonName(@JsonProperty("first") String first, @JsonProperty("last") String last) {
      this.first = first;
      this.last = last;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any simplest solution?