# How to avoid complex Model class in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a json request message which I am going to receive in my restcontroller.

```
{
 address:{
    addressline:{
        phone:{
            primary:"989898000",
            secondary:"00909000"
        }
    }
    addressline:{
     ///
    }
 }
}
```

then I should be having several model classes like this to receive this message.

```
Model{
  Address address;
}

Address{
  List<AddressLine> addressline;
}

AddressLine{
  Phone phone;
}

Phone{
  String primary;
  String secondary;
}
```

Can I skip all these model class creation and have just one class only . 
something like this :

```
Model {
 String primaryInphoneInaddresslineInaddress;
 String secondaryInphoneInaddresslineInaddress; 
}
```

This could reduce a lot of boilerplate code and can be useful also when we are going to extract message from this json message and also If we need to insert any value in the model class(if required).

Comment: Sure. Why not encode your entire application as a one billion character string while you're at it? Simpler!

Comment: The ultimate answer you'll have is when you do this in real application , try it

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michael I may try to do as what you say if I could make the life of developers only a little easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating flat object form nested json with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749777/creating-flat-object-form-nested-json-with-jackson)